# How to run module from command line?

Tags: python

Suppose there is a module somewhere, which I can import with

```
from sound.effects import echo
```

How can I run `echo` directly from command line?

Command

```
python sound/effects/echo.py
```

does not work since the relative path is generally incorrect

Comment: *the relative path is **generally** incorrect* what does that mean?

Comment: maybe `python -m sound.effects.echo` ?

Comment: @TimCastelijns it may become correct if I do `cd /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/` before that command

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the module has top-level code executing on import, you can use the [`-m` switch](https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-m) to run it from the command line (using Python attribute notation):

```
python -m sound.effect.echo
```

The module is then executed as a script, so a `if __name__ == '__main__':` guard will pass. See for example the [`timeit` module](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/timeit.py#l342), which executes the `timeit.main()` function when run from the command line like this.